# How to save data to different Tables?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to save the same kind of Object (from a file Computer.java) to different tables.
I have a postgresql database running locally as a docker container.
I have a table called "computers" where I currently save all incoming Data (received from MQTT server)

Basically I Receive Data, I change the data a bit, but not its basic structure (changed data is still a Computer.java object) and then i want to save the changed data to a separate Table.

I access my "computers" table via my ComputerRepository Class

`
package com.example.springbootbackend.repository;

```
import com.example.springbootbackend.entity.Computer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;


@Repository
public interface ComputerRepository extends JpaRepository<Computer, Integer> {
    List<Computer> findAllByIdAndTimeBetween(int id, double begin, double end);
}
```

`

I save files to the table "computers" in my Database like this

`
@Autowired
ComputerRepository comprepo;

```
public void saveComputer(Computer comp)
{
    comprepo.save(comp);
}
```

`

I Tried using @SecondaryTables to create the other tables where i intended to save my new Data

```
    package com.example.springbootbackend.entity;

    import lombok.*;

    import java.util.Comparator;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Builder
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "computers")

    @SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="computers24h"),
    @SecondaryTable(name="computers7d"),
    @SecondaryTable(name="computersPermanent")
    })

    @IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
    public class Computer implements Comparator<Computer>{

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Id
    private String computerName;

    @Id
    private double time;

    @Column(name = "value", nullable = false)
    private double value;


    public Computer(){}
    public Computer(int id, String computerName, double time, double value){
        this.computerName = computerName;
        this.id = id;
        this.time = time;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

I was hoping I computerRepository would have a function with an argument that decided in which table to save the new data, but it always just gets saved to the old "computers" table.

Comment: The @SecondaryTables annotation is used to define multiple tables for a single entity, but it does not provide a way to select a specific table when saving the entity.

Comment: In general is used to replace OneToOne relationships